# how to change janrain engage facebook sigin in text color

Tags: janrain

I am using janrain engage facebook signin for my website, i have customized the button.
Could not chnage the facebook signin text color.
I tried `janrain.settings.fontColor = '#fff';` , but its not working.

Please help me in changing the text color for janrain engege facebook engage.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That setting for janrain.settings.fontColor only changes the color of the action text at the top of the widget.

If you have a custom button and have Engage Pro or above, you should be able to use **janrain.settings.custom = true;** and use **janrain.engage.signin.triggerFlow(*provider*)** to create your own custom buttons for each social provider (if you're not using this already). There's documentation here: http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/widgets/social-sign-in-widget/users-guide/coding-the-widget-appearance/